# Server Not Found Exception in wsadmin

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

I have a jython script to create a server, deploy and application and then start the server.

But I am geeting the following exception while running it.

```
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "myfile.py"; exception information: javax.management.MBeanException[[ com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: Server, SERVERNAME, not found.
```

Here is the **entire code**... http://snipt.org/BMaf4

**Update**: He is the entire log http://snipt.org/BNZ1

Can't figure out where I am going wrong.

**But** When I am issuing a start all servers in wsadminlib.. the server gets started

Comment: Is this the entire output? Otherwise it would probably help if you could add that as well as it would be easier to see where in your script you get the exception.

Comment: @DanielBarbarian I have added the entire shell output.

Comment: Can't see anything obvious other than it seems like the log output you provided does not seem to match the script entirely. I assume this is because you have made many attempts. It just makes it a bit harder to follow.

Comment: What WAS version are you running, also have you tried to use the startServer command using only the server name as a parameter?

Comment: Don't care about the names in the script I modified it to hide the product name (company policy). 

The thing is the same script runs fine for other wars.

@DanielBarbarian

Comment: @DanielBarbarian Do you have a similar script that does the same so that I can reference for the same. I m using WS 8.5x

Comment: Not one that creates servers, but unless you already have done so you should really have a look at wsadminlib, that should also help in the future. https://github.com/wsadminlib/wsadminlib

Comment: @DanielBarbarian Using wsadminlib also I m getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the server configurations...

```
#Sync the Nodes
Sync1 = AdminControl.completeObjectName( "type=NodeSync,node="+ NODE_NAME +",*")
print "Getting Sync Info.. " + "\n" + Sync1
AdminControl.invoke(Sync1, 'sync')
print NODE_NAME + " Sync Completed.. "
```

We have to sync the nodes first before trying to start the server.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be in the way how you deploying and/or configuring your application.

```
# Your script sample
# Deploy the WAR
APP_PATH= APP_HOME + '/MYAPP/CycleWAR/war/MYAPPCycle.war'
ARGS_LIST='.....'

AdminApp.install(APP_PATH, ARGS_LIST)
```

You need to add another parameter into your arguments list `ARGS_LIST : args = "[-server " + SERVER_NAME + "]"`

```
# Since 6.0.X version
# Server Deployment
args = "[-server " + serverName + "]"

# Cluster Deployment
# args = "[-cluster " + clusterName + "]"
AdminApp.install(applicationFilePath, args)
```